# Replace multi-line string in terminal

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write some code which will overwrite its previous output e.g. the original output is `"1"` but the `"1"` is replaced with a `"2"`. This makes it look as though the `"1"` had never been outputted in the first place.
I have a list of lists called `board`, I convert this list into a multi-line string using this code:

```
rendered_board = ""
for y in range(board_height):
    for x in range(board_width):
        rendered_board += board[y][x]

    rendered_board += "\n"
```

I get the string I want, However, I want to be able to update this string with a new one and have it replace the old.

Example output :

```
+-------+                      +-------+
|       |  *gets replaced by*  |       |
|       | -------------------> |   *   |
|       |                      |       |
+-------+                      +-------+
```

Currently I have been trying to do this by using `end="\r"`
e.g.

```
print(rendered_board, end="\r")
update_board()
print(rendered_board, end="\r")
```

This has resulted in this output:

```
+-------+
|       |
|       |
|       |
+-------+
+-------+
|       |
|   *   |
|       |
+-------+
```

Comment: Can you add boardlegth, board and boardheight values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified if you need solution working on Linux or Windows.

For Linux you can use [zwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44466967/446792) answer. However *curses* module is not available on Windows.

Windows **cmd** is very simple and doesn't understand advanced formatting.
You have clear and redraw the whole window to get animation.

Here is an example of a star moving randomly on board for 20 frames of animation:

```
import os
import time
import random
import copy


board = [['+', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '+'],
 ['|', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'],
 ['|', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'],
 ['|', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'],
 ['|', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'],
 ['|', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'],
 ['|', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'],
 ['|', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'],
 ['|', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'],
 ['+', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '+']]


for i in range(20):
    os.system('cls')
    frame = copy.deepcopy(board)
    frame[random.randint(1, 8)][random.randint(1, 8)] = '*'
    print('\n'.join([''.join(i) for i in frame]))
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: There's [`UniCurses`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/UniCurses) as a drop-in replacement for using on Windows.

Answer (score 5):

That's not as trivial as you might think. You can use `\r` (carriage return) to return back to the current line, or `\b` to move a character back - both reminiscent from the early electronic typewriter days - but to go around a screen you need more control over the terminal. Sure, you can call `os.system('clear')` on *nix / `os.system('cls')` on Windows to clear the whole screen and draw it again, but that's just not elegant.

Instead, Python provides the [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#module-curses) module designed just for that purpose. Here's a simple demonstration on how to use it:

```
import curses
import time

console = curses.initscr()  # initialize is our playground

# this can be more streamlined but it's enough for demonstration purposes...
def draw_board(width, height, charset="+-| "):
    h_line = charset[0] + charset[1] * (width - 2) + charset[0]
    v_line = charset[2] + charset[3] * (width - 2) + charset[2]
    console.clear()
    console.addstr(0, 0, h_line)
    for line in range(1, height):
        console.addstr(line, 0, v_line)
    console.addstr(height-1, 0, h_line)
    console.refresh()

def draw_star(x, y, char="*"):
    console.addstr(x, y, char)
    console.refresh()

draw_board(10, 10)  # draw a board
time.sleep(1)  # wait a second
draw_star(6, 6)  # draw our star
time.sleep(1)  # wait a second
draw_star(6, 6, " ")  # clear the star
draw_star(3, 3)  # place the star on another position
time.sleep(3)  # wait a few seconds

curses.endwin()  # return control back to the console
```

Of course, you can get far fancier than this, but it should give you the idea on how to utilize it.

Comment: I dont need anything particularly fancy `os.system("cls")` may not be the update a single char and leave the rest that i would've originally wanted but it does the job and that's the most important thing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you using something like

```
print(PrintBoard, end='')
for x in len(PrintBoard):
    print("\b")
UpdateBoard()
print(PrintBoard, end='')
```

This solution uses ASCII backspace escape character \b. Also, I didn't see a point in using `end="\r"`, so I replaced it with `end=""`.

Comment: `\b` and `\r` will not work for overwriting/rescanning a multi-line output.

Answer (score -1):

I would split each board it's own list like this:

```
a = ["+-------+", 
     "|       |",
     "|       |",
     "|       |",
     "+-------+"]

b = ["+-------+",
     "|       |",
     "|   *   |",
     "|       |",
     "+-------+"]

div = ["            ",
       "  rep with  ",
       " -------->  ",
       "            ",
       "            "]
```

Then to print you can just zip them together and print..

```
for a, div, b in zip(a, div, a):
    print(a, div, b)

+-------+            +-------+
|       |  to this   |       |
|       | -------->  |   *   |
|       |            |       |
+-------+            +-------+
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP wants to print one square and then print another square, which **replaces** the old